# Windows PC Can't Detect Home Wifi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router, broadband

My fresh formatted Windows 10 PC, can't able to detect my Home wifi though it listing other available wifi networks that belong to my neighbors.
Though occasionally I can able to connect to my wifi network mostly I can't.

I was using Wifi Adapter with my CPU to detect wifi signals.
Here is the wifi searching list:
[image: wifi network list]

The above image is a reference that gives you an idea about wifi adapter is working properly, detecting active wifi networks.

Please give me some easy solution for this because I am not any kind of network engineer and a simple computer user who doesn't have deep network knowledge.

**NOTE:** I have read other similar post but I can't able to find any easy solution that I can follow at home so I am posting this new question.
If you want any more information then I am available to provide you more information.

**Router:**
D-Link DIR-615 Wireless-N300 Router

**Wireless Adapter:**
TP-LINK TL-WN821N 300 MBPS WiFi WI-FI Wireless N USB Adapter

Comment: You will need to tell us more about the router that is being used, specifically what version of 802.11 (aka WiFi) it supports, and tell us what version the computer supports.  If it sometimes works this sounds like a coverage problem.

Comment: Download the Wireless Driver for your computer (computer manufacturer's support site) and install it. Restart and test to see if that improves wireless.

Comment: Since you see your neighbor's WiFi but not your own, likely your network is hidden. See https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-connect-hidden-wireless-networks-windows-10/ to connect. Another possibility is that your machines WiFi card is incompatible with your WiFi router.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Nothing related to that because sometimes I found it within the search list and it was working fine so I don't think it's related to wifi card-related issue. Plus I have 2 cards to check, one new I have purchased for confirmation purposes.

Comment: @Ramhound how to get all this information? On the backside of the router??

Comment: @John I was using TP-Link wireless adapter with the computer so I have downloaded TP-Link my adapter model driver and installed it but still, It can't able to list my home router.

Comment: Are you able to update the firmware in the TP Link router?

Comment: I have a D-Link router and TP-Link Wireless adapter for the PC. At present, I don't know how to update the firmware in the router. I and my neighbor have the same company internet running so we both have the same router.

Comment: @Siddharth - Can you provide specifics?  There are hundreds of D-Link and TP-Link devices that exist. Indicating you have a D-Link router is not helpful information.  The specifications for your devices are published on their product page on the manufacture's website

Comment: @Ramhound I will give you the proper model number for this :)

Comment: In an [edit] to your question otherwise I and others will never see it.

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited my question with router and wireless adapter model numbers, still if you want more information then let me know.

Comment: @Siddharth - What kind of range are we talking about when the device is unable to find the network?  What kind of building material are we talking about. 802.11N (Wi-Fi 4) is more likely the reason you have encountered this problem.

Comment: @Ramhound this kind of technical term, I don't know but my PC can't able to detect my router but it can detect my neighbor router though we have the same routers placed with the same broadband service provider :)

Comment: @Ramhound Any suggestion for me?

Comment: @Siddharth - You never answered the question I asked in my last comment.

Comment: @Ramhound I am within the range of 5 metres of wifi placement and this is the wireless wifi adapter I have: https://www.flipkart.com/tp-link-tl-wn821n-300mbps-wireless-n-usb-adapter/p/itmdeudaqhm3tapr?pid=USBDEUD9FRSH9N9R&lid=LSTUSBDEUD9FRSH9N9R7WGGF5

Comment: So your laptop is within 16 feet of the router? What is the line of sight like? Have you tried switching the channel?  Are we talking 5.0 GHz or 2.4 GHz

Comment: @Ramhound It's 2.4 GHz. and I don't know how to switch the channel!! Yes, I am just in front of my router :)

Comment: You will log into the router and view the configuration for the WiFi to determine what channel it's configured to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer, I want to give credit to @Ramhound and my local network technician person to help me to solve this problem.
Thank you both of you to solve their weird problem.

Total I have talked 2 steps to solve this problem:

1. Router firmware update was pending so that I have completed
2. Change the wifi network name
3. Change the channel number of wifi signal broadcasting, before it was 13 but I made it Channel 1
   [image]

After this my windows PC which has a wireless adapter small dongle that started detecting my home wifi network.

After setting up broadband connection at home, today I am feeling relief because finally my CPU started detecting the wifi signal :)

Comment: Mine resolved by resetting from the - Web admin - DIR-615